# How to share my blog post to facebook page and group using facebook graph api

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem doing a project of my own. How to share my blog post to facebook page and group using facebook graph api.

In the facebook graph api it is written that to post a page use this.

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/feed
  ?message=Hello Fans!
  &access_token=your-access-token
```

I create a page where I am the admin of the page. My page is now live.

I have added `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permission to my api added added the token.

But when I submit the data in the above url it throws error that is shown below

```
"error": {
        "message": "(#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "H+YtIYAin/9"
    }
```

I can't find out what I am doing wrong. I have google it but did not find a solution. Thank you in advance for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using a User Token to post to your Page. You have to use a Page Token instead.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: how can I get the page access token?

Comment: that is explained in the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand now, you need some special permissions like manage_pages and pre-approved application from Facebook,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages

[Documentation link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7Gu.jpg)

I have the same problem because my app is under review.